# How do I run a windows installer via telnet using the trial version?

Tags: install4j

I'm evaluating install4j in our company.

We build a win32 installer and we are trying to set up a continuous integration environment to test it.

The CI server is able to upload the installer to the windows target machine (which is a virtualized environment) using FTP, and run batch script that looks like

```
cd c:\tmp\upload\
my_installer.exe -q -varfile response.varfile -console
```

Currently we're using the trial version of install4j 5.

When the installer is ran from the command line (cmd.exe over remote desktop) I get a popup window that warns about the trial version.
Installation is frozen until I click ok.

When the installer is ran from telnet the command just hangs and never returns. I believe the reason is that popup window.

To fully evaluate install4j we need to be able see how it fits our CI process.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You're probably best off asking them directly

Comment: I did. Nothing so far. And generally speaking, the answers I get here tend to be more trustable than anywhere else anyway :-).

Comment: As for "nothing so far", you sent an email to us yesterday evening outside our office hours, we could not have responded much earlier than that.

Comment: @Ingo Kegel. Exactly. Sorry, I didn't mean to sound like a jerk.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a restriction of the evaluation version, with a permanent license key the evaluation dialog will not be shown and the problem will go away.